# Meaning of "of the least consequence"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Excerpted from [bostonglobe.com](http://www.bostonglobe.com/ideas/2016/01/24/terrorism-and-literature/4vuLdCFcuP8buxMnAop6WI/story.html):

> When the Professor reminds a colleague “What happens to us as individuals is not of the **least consequence**,” we are jolted by the familiarity of the mind-set.

What does least consequence mean?

Comment: "Is not important " or " won't influence anything"

Comment: V.V. is right.  It's idiomatic, but you can think of it this way: something that happens to us as a result of something else is a *consequence*.  The smallest possible consequence is *the least consequence*.  And this?  This is so unimportant it doesn't even have the smallest possible consequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments says, it means "Is not important " or " won't influence anything".

We can think of it this way: something that happens to us as a result of something else is a consequence. The smallest possible consequence is the least consequence. And this? This is so unimportant it doesn't even have the smallest possible consequence.